# Using Pandas, how to I apply a formula to several rows, based on the average of previous rows given a certain condition?

Tags: python, pandas

Okay, complicated title. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

Suppose I have a dataframe of n rows filled with data from a piece of lab equipment. Every so often, that piece of equipment self-calibrates, and there will be a few rows with `True` in the `Calibrating` column. While it is calibrating, the `CalConstant` column is zero, and the uncalibrated data is saved to the `Data` column. Once it completes the procedure, it averages the `Data` and stores it in the `CalConstant` column. During normal operation, `Data` is the result of what the system measures minus the current `CalConstant`.

It turns out that this piece of equipment calculated the self-calibration constant incorrectly, and I need to re-do it by hand. This will be accomplished by averaging the `Data` column where the `Calibrating` flag is `True`, every time the instrument self-calibrates. This average will be stored in the `CalConstant` column, and will stay there in every row *until the next self-calibration*. Then it will take the average of the next self-calibration data, and apply it to the next chunk of analysis data, so on and so forth.

If we were to draw a cartoon, it would look like this. Suppose we have this dataframe:

```
Index   Data  Calibrating  CalConstant
0      49.91         True          0.0
1      49.06         True          0.0
2      50.38         True          0.0
3      47.82         True          0.0
4      51.58         True          0.0
5      11.63        False        39.75
6      10.42        False        39.75
7      11.67        False        39.75
8      10.12        False        39.75
9      10.67        False        39.75
10     10.89        False        39.75
11     11.23        False        39.75
12     10.43        False        39.75
13     11.26        False        39.75
14     10.64        False        39.75
15     50.23         True          0.0
16     52.63         True          0.0
17     49.32         True          0.0
18     50.99         True          0.0
19     51.34         True          0.0
20     12.37        False        40.90
21     11.47        False        40.90
22     10.81        False        40.90
23     13.27        False        40.90
24     12.73        False        40.90
25     11.31        False        40.90
26     12.85        False        40.90
27     10.42        False        40.90
28     11.25        False        40.90
29     10.54        False        40.90
```

Here, rows 0-4 are when the instrument is calibrating. However, it calculates the background incorrectly! It should be 49.75, and so for rows 5-14, the data is reported incorrectly. The problem repeats for the calibration on rows 15-19, and the data is incorrect for rows 20-29. **In this case, the `CalConstant` is off by 10, but in practice, the values are all over the map and not so easily fixed. This is only a cartoon. That's why I need to figure out how to apply the math, rather than just twiddling values.**

**Now then: in my data, the background calibration doesn't happen regularly, but it *does* always have the same number of entries.** I need to

1. Figure out the correct background from the `Data` column while `Calibrating` is `True`,
2. Figure out the correct `Data` by first adding back the incorrect `CalConstant`, then subtracting the correct one.

Step 2 is easy, since I can just add a new column, `CorrectCalConstant` and it's an easy formula to apply. The hard part is figuring out how to run through the data frame and find where the calibration chunk starts, grab that chunk, and only apply it until the next calibration chunk.

My actual output might look something like this:

```
Index   Data  Calibrating  CalConstant  ActualCalConstant  ActualData
0      49.91         True          0.0                0.0       49.91
1      49.06         True          0.0                0.0       49.06
2      50.38         True          0.0                0.0       50.38
3      47.82         True          0.0                0.0       47.82
4      51.58         True          0.0                0.0       51.58
5      11.63        False        39.75              49.75        1.63
6      10.42        False        39.75              49.75        0.42
7      11.67        False        39.75              49.75        1.67
8      10.12        False        39.75              49.75        0.12
9      10.67        False        39.75              49.75        0.67
10     10.89        False        39.75              49.75        0.89
11     11.23        False        39.75              49.75        1.23
12     10.43        False        39.75              49.75        0.43
13     11.26        False        39.75              49.75        1.26
14     10.64        False        39.75              49.75        0.64
15     50.23         True          0.0                0.0       50.23
16     52.63         True          0.0                0.0       52.63
17     49.32         True          0.0                0.0       49.32
18     50.99         True          0.0                0.0       50.99
19     51.34         True          0.0                0.0       51.34
20     12.37        False        40.90              50.90        2.37
21     11.47        False        40.90              50.90        1.47
22     10.81        False        40.90              50.90        0.81
23     13.27        False        40.90              50.90        3.27
24     12.73        False        40.90              50.90        2.73
25     11.31        False        40.90              50.90        1.31
26     12.85        False        40.90              50.90        2.85
27     10.42        False        40.90              50.90        0.42
28     11.25        False        40.90              50.90        1.25
29     10.54        False        40.90              50.90        0.54
```

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample data?

Comment: @jezrael done, OP was edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with `ActualCalConstant` column count by `mean` of previous `0` groups, so here `49.750` is mean of `rows 0-4`:

```
m = df['Calibrating']
s = df.groupby((~m).cumsum()[m])['Data'].transform('mean').ffill()
df['ActualCalConstant'] = np.where(df['Calibrating'], 0, s)

s1 = df['ActualCalConstant'].sub(df['CalConstant'])
df['ActualData'] = np.where(df['Calibrating'], df['Data'], df['Data'].sub(s1))
```

---

```
print (df)
    Index   Data  Calibrating  CalConstant  ActualCalConstant  ActualData
0       0  49.91         True         0.00              0.000      49.910
1       1  49.06         True         0.00              0.000      49.060
2       2  50.38         True         0.00              0.000      50.380
3       3  47.82         True         0.00              0.000      47.820
4       4  51.58         True         0.00              0.000      51.580
5       5  11.63        False        39.75             49.750       1.630
6       6  10.42        False        39.75             49.750       0.420
7       7  11.67        False        39.75             49.750       1.670
8       8  10.12        False        39.75             49.750       0.120
9       9  10.67        False        39.75             49.750       0.670
10     10  10.89        False        39.75             49.750       0.890
11     11  11.23        False        39.75             49.750       1.230
12     12  10.43        False        39.75             49.750       0.430
13     13  11.26        False        39.75             49.750       1.260
14     14  10.64        False        39.75             49.750       0.640
15     15  50.23         True         0.00              0.000      50.230
16     16  52.63         True         0.00              0.000      52.630
17     17  49.32         True         0.00              0.000      49.320
18     18  50.99         True         0.00              0.000      50.990
19     19  51.34         True         0.00              0.000      51.340
20     20  12.37        False        40.90             50.902       2.368
21     21  11.47        False        40.90             50.902       1.468
22     22  10.81        False        40.90             50.902       0.808
23     23  13.27        False        40.90             50.902       3.268
24     24  12.73        False        40.90             50.902       2.728
25     25  11.31        False        40.90             50.902       1.308
26     26  12.85        False        40.90             50.902       2.848
27     27  10.42        False        40.90             50.902       0.418
28     28  11.25        False        40.90             50.902       1.248
29     29  10.54        False        40.90             50.902       0.538
```

**Explanation**:

First are created unique groups only for `0` groups by cumulative sum [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
m = df['Calibrating']
print ((~m).cumsum()[m])
0      0
1      0
2      0
3      0
4      0
15    10
16    10
17    10
18    10
19    10
Name: Calibrating, dtype: int32
```

Then is used [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for repaet `mean` per groups:

```
print (df.groupby((~m).cumsum()[m])['Data'].transform('mean'))
0     49.750
1     49.750
2     49.750
3     49.750
4     49.750
5        NaN
6        NaN
7        NaN
8        NaN
9        NaN
10       NaN
11       NaN
12       NaN
13       NaN
14       NaN
15    50.902
16    50.902
17    50.902
18    50.902
19    50.902
20       NaN
21       NaN
22       NaN
23       NaN
24       NaN
25       NaN
26       NaN
27       NaN
28       NaN
29       NaN
Name: Data, dtype: float64
```

And last is added forward filling missing values:

```
print (df.groupby((~m).cumsum()[m])['Data'].transform('mean').ffill())
0     49.750
1     49.750
2     49.750
3     49.750
4     49.750
5     49.750
6     49.750
7     49.750
8     49.750
9     49.750
10    49.750
11    49.750
12    49.750
13    49.750
14    49.750
15    50.902
16    50.902
17    50.902
18    50.902
19    50.902
20    50.902
21    50.902
22    50.902
23    50.902
24    50.902
25    50.902
26    50.902
27    50.902
28    50.902
29    50.902
Name: Data, dtype: float64
```

Comment: The "off by 10" was just a cartoon. The calculation is different each time, and there's no constant value of error. I need to figure out how to manipulate the dataframe exactly as specified in the OP, not just subtracting 10.

Comment: It's not any formula. I don't know how the background is being calculated. I just know that it's wrong.

Comment: Everything I need to do is in the OP, including the generation of new columns if I need them.

Comment: @BenS. - Answe was edited, but not sure, if understand.

Comment: @BenS. - sorry, mea culpa, I miss title of question.

Comment: @BenS. - Super, added small explantion of solution.